# Fragmenting forms in Tab Menus: Best Approach

Tags: php, mysql, tabs

I have to prepare a form with a lot of fields (around 100). I could use one big HTML\PHP file but to improve accessibility and ease of access to the fields would rather prefer tab menus. The original form (called clinical evaluation) can be logically fragmented in 3 subforms: history, physical exam, and assessment. Now, I already have the 3 tabs in place, but I am not sure what is the best approach to use here:

a) Create 3 PHP files (history.php, physical.php, and assessment.php) putting each on a different tab, and have a submit button for each tab. This would bring also to a fragmentation of the MySQL queries: when the user is done with the history, she would hit the "finalize history" button and the relative query (corresponding to the 'history' fields in the clin_evaluation table) would start. The same of course with the remaining 2 tabs

b) Still create 3 PHP files but insert the submit button only at the end (the third tab) so to work with just one query to be sent when all data have been inserted...

What would you do ? I am inclined to use the first option, but any advice on this is greatly appreciated !

Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have an application that is heavy in forms, I use a function that I built called `form_display()`.  It takes an array like this:

```
$form = array(
    array(
        "type"  => "text",
        "label" => "Field Label",
        "name"  => "field_name",
        "class" => "optional-classes",
        "value" => "Field Value"
    ),
    ...
);
```

It then loops through this array and outputs the necessary HTML.  It saves me from writing the same HTML over and over again.  Additionally, if I change the HTML structure for forms in my application, I do it in one place.

`form_display()` returns the HTML of the form given the above type of array.  If I need to have multiple tabs, I can pass the output of multiple `form_display()` calls to `form_wrapper(), which creates the HTML and JS necessary to create a tabbed interface.

So in your case, with your form broken into three sections, you'd have three arrays that you'd pass to `form_display()`, then results of which would be passed to `form_wrapper()`, the result of which is all of the HTML and JS to make your tabbed interface form.  Additionally, you can pass to `form_wrapper()` the HTML object that is you Save button.  This way, the Save button can be outside of the tabbed interface (and accessible from anywhere in the form, not just one particular tab).

I made some sample code available [here](http://www.hyperionworks.com/forms.tar.gz), which includes the above-mentioned functions, and some snippets from one of my projects demonstrating how to use them.  The primary function, `form_display()`, is heavily commented.

Comment: Nick !! This is Awesome ! Honestly, I doubt my skills are good enough even to be able to use your solution, but the way you implemented this is outstanding :) Thanks a lot for sharing it !

Comment: Just take it once small piece at a time. Once you get the hang of it, you'll love it since it makes developing and managing forms much simpler.